# Letting know all class threads to ignore the a single event

Tags: java, multithreading

I've stumbled on a problem that I'm pretty sure I've solved in past, but just can't find a good solution at the moment.

1. Say I have multiple threads, each probing a connection.
2. In case the connection is found disconnected, the thread will re-connect and
   increase a shared counter.
3. In case the shared counter reached N, the
   current thread will also restart the remote service, and zero the
   shared counter.
4. This in turn will eventually cause all the threads
   to reconnect (and increase the shared counter again).

Question is, how do I cause all the threads to ignore this particular disconnect event, in order to prevent an early service restart (or restart loop in worse case, if there are a lot of threads)?

The enviroment is plain Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the last restart time. If you're within a short period of the last restart time, don't increase the counter.

Comment: Thanks, thought about this too but hoped there is a more elegant solution (guess I'm becoming too much spoiled by reactive programming principles).

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's hard to find a nice solution on such general problem description.

Those threads could be instructed (by the counter) to stop counting (Observer pattern) right after the counter has been reset (is 0). That behavior is also desirable under start conditions.

Then a thread would wait with the counting until the next connection attempt succeeds.

I hope it is kind of understandable.